# Grab Next Row in SQL

Tags: sql, row

I am trying to grab a field from the next row of this database. I can use the logged on time to determine the logout time but I would like to also grab the next login time so I can determine the logout [logged off] time as well. Any suggestions? Thank you

```
|-LogonDate---|-PersonID-|-LoggedOnTime---|   
|5/30 12:00pm |100       |3600            | 
|5/30 01:00pm |100       |3430            |
|5/30 03:30pm |100       |3000            |

SELECT PersonID, LogonDate, LoggedOnTime
FROM Agent_Logout
```

Comment: disregard previous comment - you are doing what it suggested.  Id have an auto-increment id as a primary key to help determine the next row.

Comment: How are you currently querying the database?

Comment: I am just doing a basic query at the moment. I have read some stuff that was saying how SQL wasn't really meant for looking at next or previous rows so I wanted to check here and see what everyone thought of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible with a analytic function. Don't know which DBMS you use but Oracle and I think also SQL Server can do it. I did it once in Oracle. There is an excellent side explaining it [here](http://www.orafaq.com/node/55) I always go there when I need this analytic functions (Usually is rather RANK). Your will need a function called LEAD. I think it would work like this:

```
SELECT PersonID, LogonDate, LoggedOnTime
       LEAD(LoggedOnTime, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY PersonID ORDER BY LogonDate, LoggedOnTime)
FROM Agent_Logout
```

Let me know if this does not work as you want (Because I haven't tested it). I will then try to go and make it work. But i am very confident ... if your database allows the syntax.

Comment: I ended up using a solution similar to this. However, MS SQL doesn't support LEAD or LAG functions. I followed this site's guide to overcome this limitation.

http://www.rafael-salas.com/2008/05/t-sql-lead-and-lag-functions.html

Answer (score 1):

You could use a sub-select to get the next LogonDate, then determine the difference between them.

```
SELECT
    a.PersonID,
    a.LogonDate,
    a.LoggedOnTime,
    (SELECT b.LogonDate
     FROM Agent_Logout AS b
     WHERE b.LogonDate > a.LogonDate
     ORDER BY b.LogonDate ASC
     LIMIT 1) AS NextLogonDate
FROM Agent_Logout AS a
```

If using MS SQL Server, remove `LIMIT 1` and add `TOP 1` here: `SELECT TOP 1 b.LogonDate`

**EDIT:** Thanks to @JYelton for pointing out `TOP 1` for MS SQL Server, and `ORDER BY b.LogonDate ASC`

Comment: If you are using SQL Server you'll need to modify the subquery: `SELECT TOP 1 b.LogonDate FROM TableName AS b WHERE b.LogonDate > a.LogonDate ORDER BY LogonDate ASC` -- The current format for the LogonDate however doesn't look like the usual SQL date format, so you may have issues with the sorting and need to convert it, but that depends on your particular SQL flavor.

Comment: This is working good but only on some records. I believe you may be right when you say the date may need to be converted. Thank you for your help and suggestions.